# react-datetime hidden behind Accordion bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datetime

as you can see I have Accordion bootstrap, in one these card bodies I'm taking the datetime input using react-datetime but it got hidden behind other card header what can I do in its CSS to change this situation or what is the best package to get datetime??? thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because accordion card style has `overflow: hidden`. you should change overflow value (with css) in your accordion menu which is hide datetime.

```
.accordion > .card {
    overflow: visible;
}
```